# Setting up Rails for the first time - is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, cpanel

I am trying to setup a Rails environment via CPanel. I've tried on several distinct hosting environments (on all of which I used CPanel to create the project) and I **always** get the following:

[image: About your rails environment - Something went wrong]

Is this something *I've* done wrong - I have to first create models/controllers etc - or something I need to bark up my hosting provider's tree about?

Comment: In retrospect, I think this would be better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: This is going to be pretty hard to answer without log snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running your app locally? If I remember correctly, for security reasons, the "about your application's environment" won't load unless it's from localhost.

Comment: That sounds like it makes sense. If you've got an URL/reference, you've got yourself a +1 and a green check, my friend!

Comment: ... or equally if  find it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in production mode (so it is recognized as it doesn't run locally), rails won't show this information, instead it will show this message.

I had this issue and wondering what's wrong when I first setup a new application in a server with passenger. The default environment of passenger is the production so it doesn't show this info. You have to set it up to development mode if you want to see them, to do that go to your virtual host file and add this:

```
   RailsEnv development
```

When you start creating your application, delete the **index.html** from the public.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum supported versions at this time are:

Ruby 1.8.7
RubyGems 1.8.25
Rails 2.3.18

Anything newer than that is a near guaranteed breakage and cPanel & WHM will be incapable of utilizing it in any way, shape, or form.

http://tickets.cpanel.net can assist you with removing your existing Ruby on Rails installations and reverting them back to cPanel supported and sanctioned versions (Ruby 1.8, RubyGems 1.8, and Rails 2). That is the only thing they can do for you at this time.

If you want to use any versions newer than this, then you will be unable to use the cPanel & WHM interfaces or management tools for it -- they simply will not work. You will then have to manually manage your RoR install by yourself through command line exclusively. None of it would fall under the scope of cPanel support.